# Select Query between dates not retrieving any data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying to retrieve the rows registered between two dates (since every time a person goes through a door a row is inserted). This way we get the "amount of visitors" on a monthly basis.
When querying the following:

```
select MOV_DATAHORA from LOG_CREDENCIAL
WHERE MOV_DATAHORA>'2017-01-01'`
```

a total of 5851 rows are shown. This is an example of a row:

```
2017-01-05 21:33:30.000
```

However when trying the following:

```
select MOV_DATAHORA from LOG_CREDENCIAL
WHERE MOV_DATAHORA>'2017-01-01' 
  AND MOV_DATAHORA<'2017-01-02'
```

0 rows are shown. I even tried the `count(MOV_DATAHORA)` statement but it still isn't working. I also tried with the `BETWEEN` statement unsuccessfully. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... the simplest explanation based on your query predicate:

```
WHERE MOV_DATAHORA > '2017-01-01' 
AND MOV_DATAHORA < '2017-01-02'
```

is that on January 1st (right after the New years) there were no visitors.

Comment: Yep, however, since the dates are in the format 'Y-d-m' i'm trying to retrieve the rows between January the first and February the first as well. I will then retrieve the data between he first and last day of each month to get the visitors on a chart using PHP later on.

Comment: Hmmm. what is the data-type of your MOV_DATAHORA column ? The standard SQL datetime format is yyyy-mm-dd so to retrieve all customers till February you would use WHERE MOV_DATAHORA > '2017-01-01' AND MOV_DATAHORA < '2017-02-01'. Can you try ?

Comment: Lol... true that, yes,I was just comparing between JAN 1st and JAN the 2nd, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a DateTime and a Date data types. Your table has a DateTime as you can see the 21:33:30.000 after the date, to convert and compare like types do the following.

```
SELECT MOV_DATAHORA FROM LOG_CREDENCIAL WHERE DATE(MOV_DATAHORA)>'2017-01-01' 
AND DATE(MOV_DATAHORA)<'2017-01-02'
```

or using between

```
SELECT MOV_DATAHORA FROM LOG_CREDENCIAL WHERE DATE(MOV_DATAHORA) BETWEEN '2017-01-01'
AND '2017-01-02'
```